OpenAPI: Defining a JSON Schema with one mandatory field and mutually exclusive optional fields
I'm creating an OpenAPI Description for an endpoint with a specific payload structure:

One field is mandatory
Two additional fields are optional
Only ONE of the optional fields can be present at a time (mutually exclusive)

Here's what I've tried:
openapi: 3.0.4
info:
  title: My API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /my-endpoint:
    post:
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              required: 
                - mandatoryField
              properties:
                mandatoryField:
                  type: string
                optionalFieldOne:
                  type: string
                optionalFieldTwo:
                  type: string


I am stuck here.


There's a third variation of required and oneOf
type: object
required:
  - mandatoryField
properties:
  mandatoryField:
    type: string
  optionalFieldOne:
    type: string
  optionalFieldTwo:
    type: string
oneOf:
- required:
  - optionalFieldOne
- required:
  - optionalFieldTwo


The easiest approach is to use maxProperties: 2 and forbid extra properties  via additionalProperties: false. This ensures that only one of the optional properties can be provided at most.
type: object
required: 
  - mandatoryField
properties:
  mandatoryField:
    type: string
  optionalFieldOne:
    type: string
  optionalFieldTwo:
    type: string
maxProperties: 2
additionalProperties: false


Another way to define mutually exclusive properties is to forbid simultaneous presence of those properties by using not + required (but schemas with not are less readable imo).
type: object
required:
  - mandatoryField
properties:
  mandatoryField:
    type: string
  optionalFieldOne:
    type: string
  optionalFieldTwo:
    type: string

# This means: if both optionalFieldOne and optionalFieldTwo are present
# then the schema is not valid
not:
  required:
    - optionalFieldOne
    - optionalFieldTwo


maxProperties works well but would only work if the schema was three properties like this example. If you have a much larger payload, you need a different method.
